# tinypng error while trying to compress image

Tags: php, curl, image-compression

I'm trying to compress image after upload it in my server and everything going as expected but when I upload my changes from local machine to online server that gives me this error

> Call to undefined function Tinify\curl_version()

so my source code in my local machine below:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify/Exception.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify/ResultMeta.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify/Result.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify/Source.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify/Client.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/tinify-php-master/lib/Tinify.php');

        \Tinify\setKey("4R8QNHlOax0Mcp7lho4QiOBUnTjJuZYj");

        if($this->upload->do_upload("file")){
            $imageDetailArray = $this->upload->data();
            $pic =  $imageDetailArray['file_name'];

            $unoptimized_img_loc = 'uploads/'.$pic;

            $img_url = base_url() . "include/" . $unoptimized_img_loc;
            try {
                $source = \Tinify\fromFile($img_url);

                $optimized_img_name = 'compressed_imgs/users_profile_pic/profile_pic'.$pic;

                $resized = $source->resize(array(
                        'method' =>'fit',
                        'width' => 300,
                        'height' =>300
                ));
                $resized->toFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/html/include/".$optimized_img_name);
            }catch (\Tinify\Exception $e){
                print_r($e);exit();
            }

            $dataIn['logo'] = $optimized_img_name;
        }
```

and the same code uploaded to my VM server and that doesn't work

Any help please
And thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2017-06-01 09:30AM CEST

Be sure that curl is activated in your **php.ini** (or maybe **curl.ini**?):

`extension=curl.so`

After adding this, restart your webserver.

---

You're missing **an installed curl package**. Install for example **php-curl**.

You didn't mention your OS and version, but here you'll find installation and configuration details: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Below, citations from https://board.s9y.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=20857 with the same casus:

> I just get this error when uploading an image with the new plugin installed: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Tinify\curl_version()` in /var/www/vps.hommel-net.de/serendipity/plugins/serendipity_event_tinypng/tinify-php/lib/Tinify/Client.php on line 11. The image is in the media library after this error but it's not compressed.
>
> Is it possible that you have no php curl module active? A package like php-curl?
>    I will have a look whether the Tinyfy-Client really needs it, but that is possible.
>
> That was the thing. The debian package is php5-curl. After installing it the error is gone. 
>   `It seems that the API of TinyPNG has counted my tries with the error, too.`

*Keep in mind the API of TinyPNG counts your number of requests!*

Comment: 7Thanks for your response my server is ubuntu and php version 7 and curl package is already exist that known when try to install curl package as below php-curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Ok, thanks for additional info. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

\Tinify\setKey("B2JCcCK0FqVfDrPyrjX5QW1jYqF7n4vl"); //pass your actual API key

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $supported_image = array('image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');

    if (in_array($_FILES['myfile']['type'], $supported_image)) {

        $src_file_name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];

        if (!file_exists(getcwd().'/uploads')) {

            mkdir(getcwd().'/uploads', 0777);
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], getcwd().'/uploads/'.$src_file_name);

        //optimize image using TinyPNG
        $source = \Tinify\fromFile(getcwd().'/uploads/'.$src_file_name);
        $source->toFile(getcwd().'/uploads/'.$src_file_name);

        echo "File uploaded successfully";
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file format.';
    }
}
```